# Is it possible to make a picture transparent in beamer?

Tags: beamer, diagrams

Here is my `MWE`.

```
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent=15}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}

    \begin{block}<1->{(test)}
        test        
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}<2->{Problem}
text comes here
    \vspace{-1.7 cm}
        \begin{flushright}
            \makebox[0.26\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.26\textwidth]{TEST.jpg}}\\
        \end{flushright}
    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem I have is that picture that is supposed to be shown in slide 2 is shown in slide 1 as well. Is it possible to solve the problem while you keep `transparent=15`?

Comment: You can physically remove it from slide 1 and only display it on slide 2. `\includegraphics` is "overlay-aware". Is that an option? It would require an additional, separate line of code for slide 1.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for your response. I can remove it or use \includegraphics<2> However, this changes the layout of my frame since I use \vspace before the picture and removing the picture changes my frame. I updated the MWE to include this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `\only<1>` you can place a `\phantom` version of your image (in order to keep the spacing, but not display it), and use the regular, overlay-aware `\includegraphics<2->` for the remainder of the slides:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{block}<1->{(test)}
    test        
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<2->{Problem}
    text comes here
    %\vspace{-1.7 cm}
    \begin{flushright}
      \only<1>{\mbox{\phantom{\includegraphics[width=0.26\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}}%
      \includegraphics<2->[width=0.26\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{flushright}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```