# Transparent figure in beamer

Tags: beamer, transition

I am trying to make a transition from one block containing text to another containing a figure. While the second block is transparent, the figure is "active", even though I specify an order of transition.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\makeatother
\title{title}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\frame{
\frametitle{Title}
\fontsize{10}{10.5}\selectfont
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{2.9in}
\begin{block}<1->{title 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item <2->this text has to appear along with the figure on the top right, but after the block;
\item <3->text;
\item <4->text;
\item <5->text;
\item <6->text;
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{1.5in}
\begin{exampleblock}<2->{title figure 1}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figures/ubuntu-logo32.png} 
\end{center} 
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}<7->{title figure 2}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figures/ubuntu-logo32.png} 
\end{center}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

And this is the wrong effect:

[image]

How could I make the figure transparent as the block in which it is contained, before "time" 2?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to change every object's opacity in pdf and if there's already a pgf/beamer solution, but this can be answered by some PDF/pgf/beamer guru. Meanwhile, as a workaround, you could include a transparent version of the image on the slides with the transparent boxes.

Comment: Related [Is it possible to make a picture transparent in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96273/is-it-possible-to-make-a-picture-transparent-in-beamer)

Comment: Now I got it, you want it fully transparent and not “greyed out”. Please ignore my comment above and sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution taken from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96273/is-it-possible-to-make-a-picture-transparent-in-beamer), we replace `scale=0.3` with `width=\linewidth` to fit box.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\makeatother
\title{title}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\frame{
\frametitle{Title}
\fontsize{10}{10.5}\selectfont
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{2.9in}
\begin{block}<1->{title 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item <2->this text has to appear along with the figure on the top right, but after the block;
\item <3->text;
\item <4->text;
\item <5->text;
\item <6->text;
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{1.5in}
\begin{exampleblock}<2->{title figure 1}
\begin{center}
\only<1>{\mbox{\phantom{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}}
\includegraphics<2->[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center} 
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}<7->{title figure 2}
\begin{center}
\only<1-6>{\mbox{\phantom{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}}
\includegraphics<7->[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{center}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I accept your answer. Though, I prefer to specify width and height to something like this: \includegraphics[width=1.1in,height=0.7in]